# Why Does an Array Cast as IEnumerable Ignore Deferred Execution?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, generics

I ran across this issue today and I'm not understanding what's going on:

```
enum Foo
{
    Zero,
    One,
    Two
}

void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> a = new Foo[]{ Foo.Zero, Foo.One, Foo.Two};
    IEnumerable<Foo> b = a.ToList();

    PrintGeneric(a.Cast<int>());
    PrintGeneric(b.Cast<int>());

    Print(a.Cast<int>());
    Print(b.Cast<int>());
}

public static void PrintGeneric<T>(IEnumerable<T> values){
    foreach(T value in values){
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

public static void Print(IEnumerable values){
    foreach(object value in values){
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
Zero
One
Two
0
1
2
```

I know Cast() is going to result in deferred execution, but it looks like casting it to IEnumerable results in the deferred execution getting lost, and only if the actual implementing collection is an array.

Why is the enumeration of the values in the `Print` method result in the `enum` being cast to an `int` for the `List<Foo>` collection, but not the `Foo[]`?

Comment: what is the output of Console.WriteLine(value.GetType().Name) inside PrintGeneric?

Comment: @SimSimY `Int32`.  And it's Int32 for the `Print` when the `List<Foo>.Cast<int>()` is passed in, but `Foo` when the `Foo[].Cast<int>()` is past in.

Comment: What does this have to do with deferred execution?

Comment: @Servy I was incorrectly assuming that somehow the deferred execution was getting ignored.

Comment: @Daryl What operation is being deferred, and how would executing it later rather than earlier be relevant?  Those are the questions you should be asking yourself in deferred execution related issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because of an optimization which is unfortunately slightly broken in the face of unexpected CLR conversions.

At the CLR level, there's a *reference* conversion from a `Foo[]` to `int[]` - you don't actually need to cast each object at all. That's not true at the C# level, but it is at the CLR level.

Now, `Cast<>` contains an optimization to say "if I'm already dealing with a collection of the right type, I can just return the same reference back" - effectively like this:

```
if (source is IEnumerable<T>)
{
    return source;
}
```

So `a.Cast<int>` returns `a`, which is a `Foo[]`. That's fine when you pass it to `PrintGeneric`, because then there's an implicit conversion to `T` in the `foreach` loop. The compiler knows that the type of `IEnumerator<T>.Current` is `T`, so the relevant stack slot is of type `T`. The per-type-argument JIT-compiled code will "do the right thing" when treating the value as an `int` rather than as a `Foo`.

However, when you pass the array as an `IEnumerable`, the `Current` property on the `IEnumerator` is just of type `object`, so each value will be boxed and passed to `Console.WriteLine(object)` - and the boxed object will be of type `Foo`, not `int`.

Here's some sample code to show the first part of this - the rest is a little simpler to understand, I believe, once you've got past that:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

enum Foo { }

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo[] x = new Foo[10];
        // False because the C# compiler is cocky, and "optimizes" it out
        Console.WriteLine(x is int[]);

        // True because when we put a blindfold in front of the compiler,
        // the evaluation is left to the CLR
        Console.WriteLine(((object) x) is int[]);

        // Foo[] and True because Cast returns the same reference back
        Console.WriteLine(x.Cast<int>().GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x, x.Cast<int>()));
    }
}
```

You'll see the same thing if you try to go between `uint[]` and `int[]` by the way.

Comment: This actually wouldn't be so bad, if it were just more consistent. In this case, the `List` and the `array` should satisfy the `is IEnumerable<T>` condition, but only one exhibits the optimization.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: It's a special part of *array* equivalence in the CLR, not general `IEnumerable<T>` equivalence.

Comment: In my actual production code, I have a method that accepts IEnumerable<T> where T is an Enum.  I then call `Cast<int>` on the IEnumerable<T> when passing it to another method.  Is the solution to call `ToList()` on it?

Comment: How can `PrintGeneric` call `Console.WriteLine(int)`? Since there are no type constraints on `T` in `PrintGeneric`, won't the `WriteLine` call be compiled to `Console.WriteLine(object)`?

Comment: @Heinzi: Sorry, you're right - of course it will. But the implicit cast to `T` will convert the individual value. Will edit my answer.